# Consulta laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Tengo la siguiente funcion, esta funcion me arroja un promedio de acuerdo a las edades en el where, pero como es podria decirle que la edad este entre estas dos variables que previamente he declarado

```
    public function resultado_segmentacion(Request $request){
        $edad = $request->edad;

        if($edad == 17){
            $edad1 = 1;
            $edad2 = 17;
        }else if($edad == 59){
            $edad1 = 18;
            $edad2 = 59;
        }else if($edad == 60){
            $edad1 = 60;
            $edad2 = 100;
        }


        $promedio = DB::select('SELECT AVG(suma) AS promedio 
                    FROM(
                        SELECT AVG(avance) as Suma 
                        FROM info_medicas AS info
                        INNER JOIN activacion_participantes AS part ON info.id_part_activ = part.id_part_activ
                        WHERE part.edad BETWEEN '$edad1' AND '$edad2'
                        GROUP BY part.id_part_activ) AS suma');

        return view ("grupos.mostrar-por-sexo")
                ->with(['datos'=>$datos])
                ->with(['promedio'=>$promedio]);
}
```

Al dejarlo como se muestra en la funcion me arroja el siguiente error

syntax error, unexpected '$edad1' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Puedes probar con esto

Comment: $promedio = DB::select('SELECT AVG(suma) AS promedio 
                    FROM(
                        SELECT AVG(avance) as Suma 
                        FROM info_medicas AS info
                        INNER JOIN activacion_participantes AS part ON info.id_part_activ = part.id_part_activ
                        WHERE part.edad BETWEEN ? AND ?
                        GROUP BY part.id_part_activ) AS suma',[$edad1,$edad2]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WHERE part.edad BETWEEN ' . $edad1 . ' AND ' . $edad2 . '
```

posiblemente sea porque falta concatenar.